# Adjust the saturation of a sunburst level - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

I created a [sunburst chart](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/sunburst-series) with Highcharts. I would like a way to highlight a level, ideally by adjusting the color saturation, without affecting the color of proceeding levels.

#### What I've tried so far:

**colorVariation**[(API docs)](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.levels.colorVariation)
[my code example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/x92318z1n4?module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)
Initially, this looked like what I needed, it adjusts the color brightness of a given level, either darkening or lightening it. Unfortunately, it only takes a `to` parameter, and no equivalent `from`, the purpose of `colorVariation` seems only to graduate the color from the parent color to the given brightness modifier value.

**color**[(API docs)](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.levels.color)
[my code example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/w0nnm4v4q5?module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)
`color` can be used to change the color of a given level, this doesn't quite meet the criteria of what I wanted as it changes each section on a level to the same color. It also causes the child levels to inherit the new color, as seen in the example. Setting `colorByPoint` doesn't fix this issue either as the child level will cycle through all colors rather than matching the colors set in the level 1 parent.

#### What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: goal]

Comment: Should this "level highlight" occur at some specific event, or just "pre-highlighted"? (if event, what event?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use internal Highcharts `brighten` method for brightening colors. Below, you can find an example of how to achieve the wanted result in your case:

```
    chart: {
        height: "600px",
        events: {
            load: function() {
                Highcharts.each(this.series[0].points, function(p) {
                    if (p.id[0] === '1' || p.id[0] === '3') {
                        p.graphic.attr({
                            fill: Highcharts.color(p.color).brighten(0.3).get()
                        });
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    },
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/de3mp4tq/